# Return custom collection from Spring Data JPA query method

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I would like my custom query method to return a specific Guava collection type (`ImmutableSet` in my example).

Example:

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<User,UserId> {

  @Query("SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u WHERE... ORDER BY ...")
  ImmutableSet<User> findByxxxx();

}
```

When I try it, I get :

```
Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet<?>]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
```

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types) does not explicitly list the Guava collection types, so I am not sure if it is impossible without a new release, or if there is some configuration that is possible to make it work.

How can I instruct Spring Data JPA to use that type?

Answer (score 1):

Spring data  doesn't support collections from any third-party libraries and probably never do...

`CrudRepository` exposes an `Iterable` to you and if you want to materialize to custom collection it's up to you to do that.

By the way If you want your repository returns custom collection types you can decorate the spring data repository with yours. Like this

```java
interface JpaUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,UserId> {

  @Query("SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u WHERE... ORDER BY ...")
  Iterable<User> findByxxxx();

}
public class MyRepository {

   private final JpaUserRepository jpaUserRepository;

   @Autowired
   public MyRepository(final JpaUserRepository jpaUserRepository) {
     this.jpaUserRepository = jpaUserRepository;
   } 

   public ImmutableSet<User> findByxxxx() {
     return ImmutableSet.copyOf(jpaUserRepository.findByXXX());
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I can obviously wrap the return type in my own code, but that is not what I was asking.

Comment: Indeed I directly proposed an alternative... I updated my answer